# Rails SQL Query if null

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a rails scope using a lambda function by passing in one value:

```
"scope :for_rank, lambda {|rank| where('min_rank <= ? AND max_rank >= ?', rank, rank)}"
```

however, it is possible that max_rank is null. In this situation, I want the query to only do the 
    min_rank <= ? 
part. How can I do this?

Example:

```
"a.min_rank = 10"
"a.max_rank = 20"
"b.min_rank = 15"
"b.max_rank = nil"
```

i want the search of for_rank(15) should return both a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 scope :for_rank, lambda {|rank| where('(min_rank <= ? AND max_rank IS NOT NULL AND max_rank >= ?) OR (min_rank <= ? AND max_rank IS NULL)', rank, rank, rank)}
```